# Macro to import CSV contents into Worksheet (without hardcoding file path)

Tags: csv, import

I would like to be able to import the contents of a CSV file into a worksheet in my macro-enabled workbook without hardcoding the path of the CSV file.  This would be so that anyone can run the macro on their computer by having the CSV file in the same folder as the workbook.

```
Sub LOAD_CME_FUT_RAW()
'
' LOAD_CME_FUT_RAW Macro
'


'
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;**C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Company\136921\cmeg.fut.prf.csv**", Destination _
    :=Range("$A$1"))
    .CommandType = 0
    .Name = "cmeg.fut.prf"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 _
    , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be sure to read the [tour] as well as [ask] as it can help you write posts that are more likely produce the desired result for both you and the community